# Is it possible to implement AWS free RTOS on nrf51822?

Tags: aws-iot, aws-greengrass

Is it possible to implement AWS RTOS on nrf51822? If not what is the alternative solution for connecting nrf51822 to IoT cloud?

Comment: nRF51822 projects often end up severely memory constrained, so that will be a primary thing to look out for.  Given that this is a BLE (or related simple 2.4 GHz schemes) radio and not something that supports WiFi or a traditional conduit for IP networking, how would you even be putting it in contact with AWS?   It seems you'll need a hardware gateway, so doing some protocol translation there also becomes an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NRF51822 is a Bluetooth low energy device, which is mostly chosen for low power applications. It cannot access the internet using Bluetooth (unless your idea is to access the internet using bluetooth or something of that sort). If your application needs internet access, you should be moving to 802.11a/b/g/n or 2G/3G/4G.

So if internet access if what you're looking after, you can choose other options like the Noode MCU, ESP8266 or ESP-32. These are WiFi devices can can access the internet using the IP Stack.

Here you'll be able to use AWS Free RTOS, ChibiOS and other RTOS based systems with the MQTT library